# Select multiple values then proceed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two div's and i want to select first upper div value then lower div value. and pass both the values to next page.

here's my code:

```
   <div id="upper">
     <a href="#">Link</a>
   </div>

  <div id="lower">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
```

if upper value is not selected then it should not go to the next page and when both values are selected then it should go on to next page.

what are the possible solutions.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: didn't get it. What value are you supposed to get?

Comment: First of all, a `div` does not have a `value`. So what exactly are you referring to, the content inside the div?

Comment: Actually in upper div there's tree view data and in lower div the action to that particular selected data. and got it upper div value in js. but not able to send it with anchor tag to next page!

Comment: if you want to chose 2 values and use it somethere else, you need to use form. also you can use localstorage

Comment: @Roope yeah the data inside the div.

Comment: do you want to transfer innerHTML of both divs?

Comment: @kpblc okay. but how to stop action of anchor tag clicked as i have to collect both the values and then proceed

Comment: write data after a span click for example. first click span 1, then click span 2. some data will be written on local storage, and after this, make link unable - anchor is not needed.

Comment: Your question seems unclear. It will be great if you can shed some light about the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html

```
<span class="span_to_remember" data-my-data="myData1">
  data1
</span>

<span class="span_to_remember" data-my-data="myData2">
  data2
</span>

<span class="span_to_remember" data-my-data="myData3">
  data3
</span>

<span class="span_to_remember" data-my-data="myData4">
  data4
</span>
```

js(jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".span_to_remember").click(function() {

    var spanData = $(this).data("my-data");
    // also you can grab html with 
    // var spanData = $(this).html();

    localStorage.setItem('param1', spanData);


  });

});
```

after you write something on first page, you can read it on other page with

```
localStorage.getItem('param1');
```

info will be available for user on every page, even if he close browser, and return to website later